# Unable to send credentials in CORS request

Tags: vue.js, cookies, axios, cross-domain, vue-resource

I have an application where the Vue front-end is on a different domain than the server. Specifically, Vue is located on `localhost:8080` and the server is located on `localhost:4000`.

During successful logins, the server responds with an HttpOnly cookie that has a session key. Here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: Cowboy
date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 22:35:46 GMT
content-length: 59
set-cookie: _myapp_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAABBndWFyZGlhbl9kZWZhdWx0bQAAAUNleUpoYkdjaU9pSklVelV4TWlJc0luUjVjQ0k2SWtwWFZDSjkuZXlKaGRXUWlPaUpWYzJWeU9qSWlMQ0psZUhBaU9qRTBPVEl5TURrek5EY3NJbWxoZENJNk1UUTRPVFl4TnpNME55d2lhWE56SWpvaVFYTndhWEpsSWl3aWFuUnBJam9pWWpreU5tVmpZek10TVRrM1lTMDBPREkyTFRrek5tSXRaRGxsTURneE5UUTNZVEpsSWl3aWNHVnRJanA3ZlN3aWMzVmlJam9pVlhObGNqb3lJaXdpZEhsd0lqb2lZV05qWlhOekluMC43THdySDUxb1hVVFR3OEhYMzBPWDJTeTd0Si05RTFFZEpQV3ZDLS1WU3YycllpZ29aTUY4NkhUMzB6Q29SWXFBajlxYXFQc0dqTzNNNFJyOHYyY1ZGZw.2k1A4HuW6VV8ACZhgHY6Szuf5gXKAe_QwMCN3doi9D4; path=/; HttpOnly
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: qi2q2rtt7mpi9u9c703tp7idmfg4qs6o
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
access-control-expose-headers: 
access-control-allow-credentials: true
vary: Origin
```

However, subsequent requests made with Vue Resource don't send this cookie back to the server, even though I'm including the `credentials: true` option:

```
this.$http.get("http://localhost:4000/api/account/", {credentials: true}).then(response => {
  //do stuff
}, response => {
  console.log(response.body.error)
})
```

I know the credentials aren't included because I can see the request header in Chrome:

```
GET /api/account/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.6
```

As such, I get a 401 Unauthorized response from the server.

Do I need to do something special to have this cookie sent back to the server during requests?

**Update 1:** Also tried with axios, using `withCredentials: true`. Same result.

**Update 2:** Upon further examination, this seems to be because the browser does not save the cookie for some reason, despite the fact that it arrives with the response. Maybe the fact that it's a single-page application has to do with this. I guess this brings up the question though: how to use session cookies with SPAs?

Comment: `Vue.prototype.$http = axios.create({ withCredentials: true });` should be what you need. Is this how you're specifying it?

Comment: I do this with axios: `this.axios.create({withCredentials: true}).get("http://localhost:4000/api/account/").then(...)`

Comment: If your server is sending a set-cookie header, this should be managed by the browser itself. The only thing that might be causing this issue here is that you are not on the same domain. Try to set virtual hosts with a dummy domain name for both frontend and backend and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, this was actually the issue. I forgot to post it as an answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Two issues. First, the cookie was arriving at the browser with domain `localhost` but I was actually making the requests to a dummy domain that I had simply mapped to localhost. Because the domains didn't match, the browser didn't send the cookie.

Second, here is the correct way to use the `withCredentials` option in Axios:

```
axios.create({withCredentials: true}).get(/* ... */)
```

Setting the option inside the request itself didn't work for some reason.